# Batch file command to open excel\csv as notepad

Tags: excel, csv, batch-file, notepad

I can open an excel file from .bat by simply using the path of the file.

Is there a parameter to open the csv in edit mode (as notepad) ?

Comment: notepad file.csv

Answer (score 0):

As Squashman mentioned in the comments, if you are just in the command prompt and need to edit any file, you can simply run `notepad <filename>`.  However, if you need this to be part of a larger batch file or want it to be in batch form for another reason, you can use the below example which does a couple notable things:

1. Accepts the filename as a parameter.
2. Uses `START` so that the batch file will exit/resume immediately. If you leave this out, the batch file will wait for you to close notepad.

> **editfile.bat**
>
> ```
> @echo off
> set "f=%1"
> echo Opening %f% in notepad.exe
> START notepad %f%
> ```

Usage:  `editfile filename.csv`

Obviously, it doesn't have to be a CSV file. It can be any file.